# Как нарисовать стрелку

Tags: java, android

Как можно нарисовать стрелку в android используя xml для drawable, все что я смог это стрелка нарисованная в gimp, [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
и совсем не красивая и кривая,

Comment: Если вам нужна именно такая стрелка, именно в ActionBar, то используйте homeAsUpIndicator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для иконок элементов управления лучше использовать png.
Я использую в своих проектах material design icon pack
там все нужные иконки на все случаи жизни для всевозможных dpi

https://github.com/google/material-design-icons

вот например белая стрелка:

https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/blob/master/navigation/drawable-hdpi/ic_arrow_back_white_48dp.png

и черная:

https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/blob/master/navigation/drawable-hdpi/ic_arrow_back_black_48dp.png

Comment: P.S. ну и если уж совсем хочется свою иконку сделать самостоятельно, то я бы рекомендовал вам использовать не растовый редактор, типа gimp, а рисовать в векторах например в inkscape - освоив пару уроков на inkscape даже "программист" способен нарисовать в векторах простую аккуратную иконку своими дрожащими руками.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я знаю - никак. Зато есть просто тьма бесплатных иконок, в том числе и [от гугла](https://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html). Скачайте и пользуйтесь. Стрелка там тоже есть.